# Table number in the caption of table in latex

Tags: latex, caption

I was using Latex to create my project report. I have used several tables in several different chapters, the captions of every table begins with table 1, table 2.... table n.

The captions don't refer to chapters the table belongs to like table 2.1 or table 6.1 and so on.

Comment: Please read [this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about requesting urgency from volunteers.

Answer (score 0):

In all Latex classes (as well as most publication guidelines) I am aware of, tables are numerated sequentially without regards to the section or chapter.

However, in case you do want a different numbering schema, have a look at the [chngcntr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr?) package. The following snippet produces table numbers prefixed with the corresponding chapter number.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{table}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
\end{tabular}
  \caption{XY}
\end{table}

\chapter{B}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
\end{tabular}
  \caption{YZ}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEOsM.png)